# Why isn't commentCount being updated in my test?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mocha.js, supertest

I have a `Post` model and a `Comment` model. When a user posts a comment, the `postID` will be sent as a param.

Once the comment is saved, it's `id` will be pushed into the `comments` array that belongs to the post.

The `Post` model has a `commentCount` which is a virtual property, which will count how many comment IDs are in the `comments` array.

This is my commentController:

```
  create(req, res, next) {
    const commentProps = req.body;
    const postId = req.params.id;

    Comment.create(commentProps)
      .then(comment => {
        Post.findById({ _id: postId })
          .then(post => {
            console.log(post);
            console.log('comment id is ' + comment._id);

            post.comments.push(comment._id);

            console.log(post);
            console.log('commentCount is ' + post.commentCount);
          });
        return res.send(comment);
      })
      .catch(next);
  },
```

All the logs are coming through just as they should be. The `comment._id` gets pushed right into the `comments` array and the `commentCount` has been incremented by `1`.

Yet my test assertion is not passing:

```
it('POST to /api/comments/:id creates a new comment and increases posts commentCount', done => {
    const post = new Post({
      author: user._id,
      text: 'This is a post',
      createdAt: 0,
      expiresAt: 0,
      voteCount: 0
    });

    post.save()
      .then(() => {
        Comment.count().then(count => {
          request(app)
            .post(`/api/comments/${post._id}`)
            .send({
              author: user._id,
              text: 'This is a comment',
              createdAt: 0,
              postId: 'randomPost'
            })
            .end(() => {
              Comment.count().then(newCount => {
                console.log('Comment count is ' + post.commentCount);

                assert(count + 1 === newCount);
                assert(post.commentCount === 1);

                done();
              });
            });
        });
      });
  });
```

The log in the test above comes back as `0` and if I log the `post.comments` then it just comes back as an empty array.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here guys?

Thanks!

Comment: What's post.save ( ) look like?

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean? It's saving it to the mongoDB

Comment: I'm confused by a couple of things. "post" doesn't have a commentCount property (according to your declared const), in fact I don't see anywhere where that property is shown as part of any object at all. So either that's not right, or that property/value is getting added somewhere that I can't see here. I figured it might be in the logic of the promise that is getting returned by "save".

Comment: Oh I'm using Mongo, it's declared in the Model Schema. I don't (or shouldn't) need to declare it when I create the object. It'll be an empty array when the postis created.

Comment: right now, if I console log the post in the test, it logs an empty array